# What are all the marriages and child relationships following the final chapter?

Tags: naruto

In the last chapter of *Naruto*, some characters got married, and some of them had kids. What is the entire husband-wife-kids set?

Comment: Having just started watching the original Naruto episodes again, episode 42, 00:05:14 -> 00:05:19 shows a very infatuated looking TenTen staring at Rock Lee training.
This, in addition to other hints in the '31 points' answer as well as clues about Hanabi not being the mother from the new Boruto series, my best guess is, until confirmed, that Rock Lee and TenTen are together.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Naruto and Hinata - [Bolt (Boruto)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki) and [Himawari](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Himawari_Uzumaki)
Sasuke and Sakura - [Salad (Sarada)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sarada_Uchiha)
Shikamaru and Temari - [Shikadai](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shikadai_Nara)
Chouji and Karui - [Chouchou](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ch%C5%8Dch%C5%8D_Akimichi)
Ino and Sai - [Inojin](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Inojin_Yamanaka)
Kurenai and Asuma - [Mirai Sarutobi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mirai_Sarutobi)

Kiba is shown with [Tamaki, but we don't even know if there's anything going on between them](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tamaki#Epilogue).

Rock Lee is shown training with a kid that looks like him, and Tenten is shown right after that, so maybe that's their kid, or maybe some kid who emulated Lee like he had emulated Guy before.

Here's an image that summarises all the characters seen in the 700th chapter, including the pairings and their children:

[image: pairings and whatnot]
Click to enlarge. Source: [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/2lj571/today_naruto_ended_so_i_made_a_chart_of_all_the/)

Comment: The girl Kiba is with is the granddaughter of the cat master shown in some anime episodes in part one. [Tamaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tamaki)

Comment: @JNat   The latest Boruto manga suggests a little change in sasuke-sakura pair. Could you please edit your answer?

Comment: @SeasonalShot If you mean chapter 700+1, it's still not confirmed. I'll edit it _if_ it gets confirmed :)

Comment: Ok. I guess that's appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

**I found a good picture showing all the relationships. Here it is.**

[image]

**This is yet another picture depicting the family tree.**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As for the kid training with Rock Lee, I think that Rock Lee’s wife and baby mama is going to end up being Hanabi Hyuuga.

Here are my reasons:

1. Hanabi is about to play a much bigger role in the anime – the final movie is about her getting kidnapped and a bunch of Konoha shinobi having to go on a rescue mission.  She even has a super cute new character design to match her new significance.  HOWEVER… the movie is supposed to come between chapter 699 and the full-color epilogue, and we were given NOTHING about Hanabi in that epilogue.  So that would either mean that she went from suddenly super relevant to irrelevant in a few chapters… OR that Kishimoto-sensei left Hanabi’s fate open-ended for a reason.
2. Speaking of the full-color epilogue, take a good look at Lee’s nameless protégé (presumably son – and son according to Narutopedia Wiki).  Focus on his eyes for a second, and tell me they don’t look more like Neji’s than they do Lee’s.
3. Hanabi and Lee are both taijutsu experts, and that means they automatically have something in common.  The fact that Hyuugas always focus heavily on taijutsu matches the image of Lee’s son studying taijutsu intently with his father.
4. We already know that Naruto and Hinata end up together and have children.  If Lee and Hanabi ended up together, this would mean that Naruto and Lee’s children are first cousins.  That could be a considered a nod to the relationship between Kakashi and Gai (Naruto and Lee’s senseis).
5. Hyuugas have always married their cousins to keep their bloodline pure.  Since Hinata ended up with Naruto, this would have meant that Hanabi would have been the match for Neji.  However, as we know, Neji dies.  It seems fitting that Neji’s male teammate would step up to fill that role.

Comment: your 5th point conflicts with itself, *"Hyuugas have always married their cousins to keep their bloodline pure"* that would mean Lee is struck out as a candidate, being a team mate of a branch family member doesn't make Hanabi x Lee magically as pure as Hanabi x any branch family member, this is also enforced that Hinata probably was only allowed to marry Naruto because either he is the Hokage (which Lee is not) or that because Hinata is not going to be the next head so her offspring is of no concern to the head family (they end up as a new branch family) while Hanabi is to be the next head

Comment: You have a good point - it would be ideal for her to marry another Hyuuga, but neji is dead and there are no other male children in the bloodline. She probably had to marry somebody else just to keep the genes alive at all. I just think it makes for another tie between her and lee. But it's just a headcanon/fan theory anyway at this point. :P