# Was it already revealed in the manga who will be the wives of Naruto and Sasuke?

Tags: naruto

From the first episode of Naruto (season 1) until the last episode of Naruto Shippuuden, Naruto has a crush on Sakura, who in turn Sakura has crush on Sasuke (Ino also has crush on Sasuke).
I've been wondering if who will be the wives of Naruto and Sasuke has already been revealed in the manga? Since both of them are already matured. There are some speculations  that Naruto will be the husband of Sakura (just saw it on FB- an image).

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14890/49)

Comment: The manga series have ended plus the last movie is also out.  Be prepared for spoilers.

Answer (score 1):

The very last Naruto Shipuuden manga (issue 700) does reveal who gets married to whom.

Don't hover if you don't want to know:

> Naruto marries Hinata and Sasuke marries Sakura

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved because the last chapter of Naruto has come out.

Here are the pairings (that you mentioned):

> Naruto marries Hinata and they have two children: Boruto Uzumaki (son) and Himawari Uzumaki (daughter) 
>  Sakura marries Sasuke and they have one daughter: Sarada Uchiha, 
>  Ino marries Sai and they have one son: Inojin

Because I can't link to scanalations, here are the Naruto Wikia pages for these characters:

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura_Haruno

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ino_Yamanaka

Here is the Wikia page for chapter 700, where all of the pairings are revealed:

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki!!_(chapter_700)